# mod_php5 as a static apache module in a cpanel environment

Tags: php, apache, whm, static, module

One source claims that apache would perform about 5% slower when using modules that are dynamically loaded (shared). Because of this, I want to be able to make PHP on the server run faster by converting the dynamic module to a static module. But I'm not 100% sure if this will work.

Someone made a post at http://dan.drydog.com/apache2php.html stating that:

> I was only able to get PHP working with Apache 2 as a *.so DSO ("dynamic shared object"), as opposed to compiled into Apache (with a static *.a library). I think DSO is the only way PHP is supported now on Apache 2.

I feel that only applies to certain mod_php5 apache modules, but I'm not 100% sure.

I want to run EasyApache (tool bundled with WHM), select custom modules and have mod_php5 statically compiled (not dynamically compiled). There is no option for this in the EasyApache program itself. Is my idea possible now if I have the correct version of an apache PHP module? and what is the best procedure to do this?

I don't want to try converting a dynamic PHP apache module into a static module only to find out that hackers can see the PHP scripts as plain text.